# Launch app with intent when calling contact

Tags: android, android-intent

When pressing the call button in the contacts app, I want to launch my own app to call with. The only method I have found to do this is with a receiver that listens to the NEW_OUTGOING_CALL broadcast. But this is ugly and means that all calls are routed through my receiver.

At the moment I have registered multiple intent-filters on the DIAL, CALL and CALL_BUTTON intents, but none fire... I am testing on a Samsung Galaxy S7 with Android 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you wrote: `When pressing the call button in the contacts app, I want to launch my own app. . . .` then `But this is ugly and means that all calls are routed through my receiver`, both parts are in contrast.
The best way (and I think the only one since contact app is not "yours", it's owned to OS), is as you did, with a receiver.
What I can suggest to you is to add a custom filter(programmatically) within your `onReceive` method and to ask when it get awake to ask if the contact is the requested and then open your app via `Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that using a Broadcast receiver is actually the recommended way of doing  this. It's not possible to actually change the calling application; that's pretty much bound to the OS. Even with a rooted device, you'd have issues.